# Included chef cookbook provider not working

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I'm trying to use `gem_specfic_install` cookbook so I can use the `SpecificInstall` provider but chef just doesn't seem to accept it's there.

I've added `cookbook 'gem_specific_install', '~> 0.2.4'` to my berksfile
I've added `depends 'gem_specific_install'` to my metadata.rb
I've added `include_recipe "gem_specific_install"` to my install recipe file

Chef errors no matter which way I use it (as specified [here](https://github.com/optiflows-cookbooks/gem_specific_install))

What am I doing wrong?

p.s. the reason I'm trying to use this is because I need to install `event_machine` gem from it's github repo as that contains a fix that the .gem on rubygems.com doesn't have.

Would it be worth downloading the fixed version, build the .gem file and host it locally or on our artifactory server instead of using specific_install ?
EDIT:

It either goes:

```
[2014-10-27T17:36:16+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `repository' for Chef::Resource::GemPackage
```

or

```
options takes a string not a hash
```

EDIT:
Doesn't really matter any more, managed to fix my problem by using normal gem_package, I realised what I was doing wrong, still I do want to know why specific_install wasn't working.

Comment: Please add the text of the error to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you want to use the `repository` attribute, you need to use the `gem_specific_install` resource directly instead of `gem_package`. I don't think the second form using the options string is actual viable given changes in Chef.

Comment: hmm the version I was actually using was from https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/gem_specific_install/versions/0.2.2 still, I got it to install any way so it's not a problem now. thanks for your help.

Comment: That version is out of date with respect to Chef.